# How to fix this 2D array loop without going out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to write code that takes in 4 parameters (row of a tic-tac-toe board, column, the row increment, and the column increment) which is to move through the tic-tac-toe board and return the highest sequence of the symbol inside of the row and column given.

I have it mostly working, except I know that my code is faulty in that it cannot distinguish between instances where it should return 2 vs 3 (it returns 2 rather than 3), but after a solid day of trying every possible thing I could think of, most of my attempted fixes only made it more complex while causing the test to return an out of bounds exception error.

Can somebody please offer some advice as to how I could go about fixing this?

```
public int getMaxSequence(int row, int column, int dr, int dc, char symbol) {
    int maxSequence = 0;
    List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    sequence.add(0);

    for (int i = row, j = column; i <getBoard().length-1 && j < getBoard()[i].length-1; i = i+dr, j = j + dc){
        if (this.board[i][j].getSymbol()== symbol && this.board[i+dr][j+dc].getSymbol()!= symbol){
            sequence.add(1);
        }
        else if (this.board[i][j].getSymbol()== symbol && this.board[i+dr][j+dc].getSymbol()== symbol){
            sequence.add(2);
        }
        else if (this.board[i][j].getSymbol()== symbol && this.board[i+dr][j+dc].getSymbol()== symbol 
                && this.board[i+dr+dr][j+dc+dc].getSymbol()== symbol){
            sequence.add(3);
        }

        maxSequence = Collections.max(sequence);

        if (isWithinBounds( row+dr, column+dc)!=true){
            return Collections.max(sequence);}
        }
        return Collections.max(sequence);
    }
}
```

Here is the test (line 144 marked by `/*->*/` is the obstacle thus far, since 3 is expected):

```
public class TicTacToe5x5Tests extends TestCase {
    // Piece is an immutable class so it is okay to make these constants
    // Do not make static final pieces in your tests if they are mutable
    public static final Piece X = new Piece('x');
    public static final Piece O = new Piece('o');
    public static final Piece E = new EmptyPiece();
    public static final Piece B = new BlockedPiece();

    public static TicTacToe5x5Game createStartGame() {
        // uses the make start game method on TicTacToe5x5Game
        return TicTacToe5x5Game.makeStartGame('o', 'x');
    }

    public static TicTacToe5x5Game createMidGame1() {
        // an example board after 2 turns each (score 1 for x, 2 for o)
        Piece[][] board = 
            {{X, E, E, E, E},
             {E, E, E, E, O},
             {E, E, B, O, E},
             {X, E, E, E, E},
             {E, E, E, E, E}};
        return new TicTacToe5x5Game(board, 'o', 'x');
    }
    public static TicTacToe5x5Game createMidGame2() {
        // an example board mid-game (score 2 for x, 3 for o)
        Piece[][] board = 
            {{X, O, O, E, X},
             {X, E, O, E, O},
             {E, E, B, O, E},
             {X, O, X, X, E},
             {E, O, X, E, E}};
        return new TicTacToe5x5Game(board, 'o', 'x');
    }
    public static TicTacToe5x5Game createEndGame1() {
        // an example board where player x has won (score 4 for x, 3 for o)
        Piece[][] board = 
            {{X, O, O, E, X},
             {X, E, O, E, O},
             {X, E, B, O, E},
             {X, O, X, X, E},
             {E, E, E, E, E}};
        return new TicTacToe5x5Game(board, 'o', 'x');
    }

    public static TicTacToe5x5Game createEndGame2() {
        // an example board where nobody has won (score 3 for x, 3 for o) but there are no more moves
        Piece[][] board = 
            {{X, O, O, O, X},
             {O, O, O, X, O},
             {X, X, B, O, X},
             {X, O, X, X, X},
             {O, X, O, O, X}};
        return new TicTacToe5x5Game(board, 'o', 'x');
    }

    public static PlacePieceAction createAction() {
        // won't be valid for all TicTacToeGame states, but just an example
        return new PlacePieceAction('x', 2, 1);
    }

    public void test_changeTurn() {
        TicTacToe5x5Game game = createStartGame();
        assertEquals('x', game.getNotTurn());
        assertEquals('o', game.getTurn());
        game.changeTurn();
        assertEquals('x', game.getTurn());
        assertEquals('o', game.getNotTurn());
    }

    public void test_PlacePieceAction() {
        PlacePieceAction action1 = new PlacePieceAction('o', 3, 1);
        PlacePieceAction action2 = new PlacePieceAction('o', 2, 2);
        PlacePieceAction action3 = new PlacePieceAction('x', 3, 0);

        // use the initial state from TicTacToe5x5
        TicTacToe5x5Game game0 = createStartGame();
        assertTrue(action1.isValid(game0)); // it is o's turn
        assertFalse(action2.isValid(game0)); // middle square is not usable by either player
        assertFalse(action3.isValid(game0)); // it is not x's turn

        // test that performing action1 will put an O at 3, 1
        action1.update(game0);
        assertEquals('x', game0.getTurn());
        Piece[][] expectedBoard1 = 
            {{E, E, E, E, E},
             {E, E, E, E, E},
             {E, E, B, E, E},
             {E, O, E, E, E},
             {E, E, E, E, E}};
        assertTrue(Arrays.deepEquals(expectedBoard1, game0.getBoard()));

        // test that performing action3 will put an X at 3, 0
        assertTrue(action3.isValid(game0)); // it is o's turn now so this is ok
        action3.update(game0);
        assertEquals('o', game0.getTurn());
        Piece[][] expectedBoard2 = 
            {{E, E, E, E, E},
             {E, E, E, E, E},
             {E, E, B, E, E},
             {X, O, E, E, E},
             {E, E, E, E, E}};
        assertTrue(Arrays.deepEquals(expectedBoard2, game0.getBoard()));
    }

    public void test_hasEmptySpace() {
        assertTrue(createStartGame().hasEmptySpace());
        assertTrue(createMidGame1().hasEmptySpace());
        assertTrue(createEndGame1().hasEmptySpace());
        assertFalse(createEndGame2().hasEmptySpace());
    }

    public void test_getMaxSequence() {
        TicTacToe5x5Game game = createMidGame2();

        // test row 0
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 0, 1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 0, 1, 'x'));
        // test row 3
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(3, 0, 0, 1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(3, 0, 0, 1, 'x'));

        // test column 0
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 1, 0, 'o'));
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 1, 0, 'x'));
        // test column 1
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(0, 1, 1, 0, 'o'));
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(0, 1, 1, 0, 'x'));

        // test down-right diagonal 1,0
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(1, 0, 1, 1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(1, 0, 1, 1, 'x'));
        // test down-right diagonal 0,1
/*->*/  assertEquals(3, game.getMaxSequence(0, 1, 1, 1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(0, 1, 1, 1, 'x'));

        // test down-left diagonal 1,4
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(1, 4, 1, -1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(1, 4, 1, -1, 'x'));
        // test down-left diagonal 2,4
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(2, 4, 1, -1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(2, 4, 1, -1, 'x'));

        // test middle square (it is not a free square, it is blocked)
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(0, 2, 1, 0, 'o'));
        assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(0, 2, 1, 0, 'x'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(2, 0, 0, 1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(2, 0, 0, 1, 'x'));
        assertEquals(0, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 1, 1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 1, 1, 'x'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(0, 4, 1, -1, 'o'));
        assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(0, 4, 1, -1, 'x'));
    }

    public void test_getScore() {
        assertEquals(0, createStartGame().getScore('x'));
        assertEquals(0, createStartGame().getScore('o'));
        assertEquals(1, createMidGame1().getScore('x'));
        assertEquals(2, createMidGame1().getScore('o'));
        assertEquals(2, createMidGame2().getScore('x'));
        assertEquals(3, createMidGame2().getScore('o'));
        assertEquals(4, createEndGame1().getScore('x'));
        assertEquals(3, createEndGame1().getScore('o'));
        assertEquals(3, createEndGame2().getScore('x'));
        assertEquals(3, createEndGame2().getScore('o'));
    }

    public void test_isWinner() {
        assertFalse(createStartGame().isWinner('x'));
        assertFalse(createStartGame().isWinner('o'));
        assertFalse(createMidGame1().isWinner('x'));
        assertFalse(createMidGame1().isWinner('o'));
        assertFalse(createMidGame2().isWinner('x'));
        assertFalse(createMidGame2().isWinner('o'));
        assertTrue(createEndGame1().isWinner('x'));
        assertFalse(createEndGame1().isWinner('o'));
        assertFalse(createEndGame2().isWinner('x'));
        assertFalse(createEndGame2().isWinner('o'));
    }

    public void test_isEnd() {
        assertFalse(createStartGame().isEnd());
        assertFalse(createMidGame1().isEnd());
        assertFalse(createMidGame2().isEnd());
        assertTrue(createEndGame1().isEnd());
        assertTrue(createEndGame2().isEnd());
    }

    public void test_AI_getAllValidActions() {
        TicTacToe5x5Game game0 = createStartGame();
        TicTacToe5x5AI ai = new TicTacToe5x5AI("o");

        List<Action<TicTacToe5x5Game>> actions = ai.getAllValidActions(game0);
        // check to make sure at least all empty space moves are in there
        int missingMoves = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (game0.getBoard()[i][j] instanceof EmptyPiece) {
                    boolean found = false;
                    for (Action<TicTacToe5x5Game> action : actions) {
                        PlacePieceAction ppa = (PlacePieceAction)action;
                        if (ppa.getRow() == i && ppa.getColumn() == j) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found) {
                        missingMoves++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        assertEquals(0, missingMoves); // should be 0 missing moves
    }

    public void test_AI_getHeuristicScore() {
        TicTacToe5x5Game game0 = createMidGame2();
        TicTacToe5x5AI aiO = new TicTacToe5x5AI("o");
        TicTacToe5x5AI aiX = new TicTacToe5x5AI("x");

        // score of mid game 2 is 3 for player o. If player o plays at 3, 4
        //  then they would win with a score of 4
        assertEquals(4.0, aiO.getHeuristicScore(new PlacePieceAction('o', 3, 4), game0));
        // score should still be 3. if this is 4 then your heuristic is mutating
        //  the board and not properly undoing its mutation.
        assertEquals(3.0, aiO.getHeuristicScore(new PlacePieceAction('o', 2, 4), game0));

        // change the turn so if the AI is checking for validity of the action the test
        //  will still work
        game0.changeTurn();
        // score of mid game 2 is 2 for player x. However, if player x plays at 2, 0
        //  then they would win with a score of 4
        assertEquals(4.0, aiX.getHeuristicScore(new PlacePieceAction('x', 2, 0), game0));
        // score should still be 2. if this is 5 then your heuristic is mutating
        //  the board and not properly undoing its mutation.
        System.out.println(game0);
        assertEquals(2.0, aiX.getHeuristicScore(new PlacePieceAction('x', 4, 0), game0));
    }

    public void test_AI_getBestAction() {
        // check to see if on board 2 they will make the move that will win the game
        TicTacToe5x5Game game0 = createMidGame2();
        TicTacToe5x5AI ai = new TicTacToe5x5AI("o");

        PlacePieceAction ppa = (PlacePieceAction)ai.getBestAction(game0);
        assertEquals(3, ppa.getRow());
        assertEquals(4, ppa.getColumn());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // print some games and sample actions
        System.out.println(createStartGame());
        System.out.println(createMidGame2());
        System.out.println(createEndGame2());

        System.out.println(createAction());
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions must be self-contained. A paste link may go nowhere in the future and the question becomes worthless without the code in question. That is why I added the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are only testing the top half of the range in your loop test:

```
for (int i = row, j = column;
    i <getBoard().length-1 && j < getBoard()[i].length-1;
    i = i+dr, j = j + dc)
```

You allow negative increments, e.g:

```
assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(1, 4, 1, -1, 'o'));
```

Therefore you need to check that the index is greater than or equal to zero or you will get an exception when the index decreases to -1.

```
for (int i = row, j = column;
    i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < getBoard().length && j < getBoard()[i].length;
    i += dr, j += dc)
```

Also, the upper range check should be less than the length or less than or equal to the length minus one, but not less than the length minus one or you will exclude the last element.